# Regular expression to negate chrome on IOS devices

Tags: javascript, regex

In my Javascript webapp, I am using below regular expression to detect ios/mac devices which works fine.

```
 var regex = \\biP\\w+; CPU(?: iP\\w+)? OS (?:1[2-9][_\\d]+|11_(?:\\d\\d+|[3-9])(?:_\\d+)?) like Mac OS X\\b;

 if(navigator.userAgent.match(regex)) {
   // do something
 }
```

Now, I would like to exclude chrome on IOS. So, I am trying below regular expression to negate the word "CriOS"(chrome on IOS) but it's not working. Please let me know what I am missing here. Thanks in Advance

```
"\\biP\\w+; CPU(?: iP\\w+)? OS (?:1[2-9][_\\d]+|11_(?:\\d\\d+|[3-9])(?:_\\d+)?) like Mac OS X\\b(?:(?!CriOS).)*$"
```

**UserAgent on Iphone Safari**
    "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.23 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1"

**Usear Agent on Iphone Chrome**
    "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1"

Comment: Could you add examples of ios/mac devices?

Comment: Sure. For example on Iphone safari, the user agent would be                                                 "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.23 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1"                                                                                                                         on Iphone chrome it would be "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/56.0.2924.75 Mobile/14E5239e Safari/602.1"

Comment: can you test this code `(?!.*CriOS.*$)\\biP\\w+; CPU(?: iP\\w+)? OS (?:1[2-9][_\\d]+|11_(?:\\d\\d+|[3-9])(?:_\\d+)?) like Mac OS X\\b` ? or just add this code `(?!.*CriOS.*$)` at the beginning of you regex.

Comment: That worked :) Thank you Ibrahim. It seems i need to append that negation at the start of the regex.

Comment: Excellent! I posted my comment as an answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the negation at the beginning of your code `(?!.*CriOS)`.

Example:

```
(?!.*CriOS)\\biP\\w+; CPU(?: iP\\w+)? OS (?:1[2-9][_\\d]+|11_(?:\\d\\d+|[3-9])(?:_\\d+)?) like Mac OS X\\b
```